# Passing Modifier.align as a parameter

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Composable as follows:

```
@Composable
private fun MoviePosterWithRating(movie: MovieModel) {
Box {
    Image(<...>)
    Box( //Rating circle
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(end = 8.dp, top = 220.dp)
            .size(48.dp)
            .background(Color.Black, shape = CircleShape)
            .align(Alignment.TopEnd)
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            progress = movie.score / 10,
            color = percentageCircleColor(movie.score),
            strokeWidth = 2.dp
        )
        Text(
            text = "${movie.score.asPercentage()}%",
            color = Color.White,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
            fontSize = 13.sp,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)
        )
    }
}
```

I would like to extract the rating circle into it's own method so I can reuse it. However, I can't because of the align on modifier. I could pass the whole modifier in as a parameter, but I would just be passing the same padding, size and background colour every time. Is there a way that I could just pass in the .align part of the modifier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you should do this is to have your composable accept a `Modifier` as parameter, that way you can pass it at the calling point, making your composable more flexible:

```
@Composable
fun RatingCircle(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    // other attributes
) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        // other composables
    }
}
```

Then you call it like so

```
Box {
    Image(<...>)
    RatingCircle(
        modifier = Modifier.align(/* alignment */)
    )
}
```

Comment: Doing something else with `Modifier` class as parameter will trigger Lint warning. I'm grateful for this warning.

Comment: Are you referring to the warning that Modifier should be the 1st argument with a default value?

Comment: Yes. I triggered lint warning by giving different default value than `Modifier` object instance.

Comment: Yes, if you check all the composables from the Jetpack Compose libraries you'll see that they all default to Modifier without any extra attributes, you should do the same - let the caller customize the composable at the call site, that's much more flexible.